# Is it posible to create a XML node with prefix in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

im trying to create an xml file with namespace or prefix like this.

`<bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_1">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="173" y="102" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Task_1_di" bpmnElement="Task_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="437" y="107" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_1_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_1">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="209" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="323" y="120" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="323" y="147" />
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="437" y="147" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds x="278" y="123.5" width="90" height="20" />
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>`

I tried with document.createElement("bpmn"); But I can't set the prefix.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There is `document.createElementNS`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-DocCrElNS, where you use `var el = document.createElementNS('http://your-namespace-uri-here', 'prefix:localnamehere')`. Should work in DOM Level 2 or 3 implementations like Mozilla or Opera or Chrome or new versions of IE offer for XML DOM documents.

```js
var ns1 = 'http://example.com/ns1';
var ns2 = 'http://example.org/ns2';

var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(ns1, 'pf1:root', null);

var el1 = doc.createElementNS(ns1, 'pf1:foo');
el1.setAttribute('id', 'e1');
doc.documentElement.appendChild(el1);

var el2 = doc.createElementNS(ns2, 'pf2:bar');
el1.appendChild(el2);

var pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.textContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);

document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

In older versions of IE however the XML DOM is only supported by MSXML and ActiveX and there you need to use a `createNode` method, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

> nodeObject.prefix=prefix

that will return:

> nodeObject.prefix

Comment: I used it but in chrome it does nothing. heres the code: 
var bpmn = document.createElement("process");
  bpmn.id = "Process_1";
  bpmn.setAttribute("tstamp",  "now");
  bpmn.prefix="bpmn"
  var Node = document.createElement("testing");
  Node.prefix = "prefix";
  bpmn.appendChild(Node);

Answer (score 0):

I think i am on the right track... here is my code. Its with createElementNS.

Thanks Martin :).

```
var container = document.createElement("root");
var bpmn = document.createElementNS('http://your-namespace-uri-here','bpmn:definitions');
    bpmn.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:xsi","http://ww w.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    bpmn.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:bpmn","http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL");
    bpmn.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:bpmndi","http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI");
    bpmn.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:di","http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI"); 
    bpmn.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:dc","http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC");

var process = document.createElementNS("task",'bpmn:process');
process.id="Process_1";
process.setAttribute("isExecutable","false");

var sequenceFlow = document.createTextNode("sequenceFlow_1");

var start = document.createElementNS("task",'bpmn:startEvent');
start.id="StartEvent_1";
var outgoing = document.createElementNS("task",'bpmn:outgoing');
outgoing.appendChild(sequenceFlow)  
start.appendChild(outgoing);

var sequenceFlow1 = document.createTextNode("sequenceFlow_1");
var incoming = document.createElementNS("incoming","bpmn:incoming");
incoming.appendChild(sequenceFlow1)

var task = document.createElementNS("task","bpmn:task");
task.id = "Task_1";
task.setAttribute("name","Titulo112");

task.appendChild(incoming);
process.appendChild(start);
process.appendChild(task);
bpmn.appendChild(process);

container.appendChild(bpmn);
```

console.debug(container);